# Property of Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure  and for any $r>0$ the set $$B(x,r)\cap A$$ is non empty. Let $D^c$ be a measure zero set and hence $D$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\cap D$ is non empty. Is it true that for any $r>0$ the set $$B(x,r)\cap A\cap D$$ is non empty?

($B(x,r) $ denotes the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: No.  Let $D$ be dense with dense complement (e.g., $\mathbb{Q}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^n$), and $A=D^c$ for example.

Comment: Okay. What if $A\cap D$ is non empty? I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: No: Add a single common point to $A$ and $D$. If you're looking for some sufficient condition that $A \cap D$ approaches $x$ in this way, you'll need something stronger known about the relation between $A$ and $D$. Also, $y$ and $t$ don't seem relevant.

Comment: Okay, I'm actually confused by the introduction. If $x$ and $y$ are given constant points, then $\forall r_1, r_2 > 0 : B(x,r_1) \cap B(y,r_2) \neq \emptyset$ implies $x=y$. If we're saying $\forall r_1, r_2 > 0 : \exists A, x, y$ with those properties, that just says $A$ is not empty, since the condition "has a point which is arbitrarily close to some other two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$", is true of any point.

Comment: Okay. I edited and add some stronger properties of $A,D$ and $y$.

Comment: Ohh sorry. Now I understand your doubt.

Comment: Forget $A$ for a moment. If $B(x,r_1)\cap B(y,r_2)\ne\emptyset$ for any $r_1,r_2>0$, then aren't $x=y$?

Comment: Okay. Since $r_2$ making so much ambiguity, let me edited out this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been edited from the original version in order to match the current formulation of the problem.

First, I comment that the extra hypothesis on $A$ is rather weak as stated. Indeed, if $A$ is nonempty then there is some $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $r>0$, $B(x,r)\cap A$ is nonempty. Just let $x$ be any point in $A$.

We can also use this to see that the answer to the question is no as stated. Let $A=[0,1]^n\cup\{x\}$ where $x$ is some point not in $[0,1]^n$ (so the hypotheses are satisfied since $x\in A$). Let $D=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{x\}$. Then $B(r,x)\cap A\cap D=\emptyset$ for small enough $r$.

In light of the comments below (on the original answer), one could instead ask:

> If $x$ is a limit point of $A$ then is it still a limit point of $A\cap D$?

Now the previous example doesn't work since $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. But we can easily modify it to work by adding a convergent sequence outside of $[0,1]^n$, rather than an isolated point. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, let $A=[0,1]\cup\{2-\frac{1}{n}:n>0\}$ (the interval $[0,1]$ is only there to ensure positive measure, it serves no other purpose). Let $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{2-\frac{1}{n}:n>1\}$. So $2$ is a limit point of $A$, but not a limit point of $A\cap D=[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. The question edited so many times that it deviates from its point. Here $x$ is a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  for all $r>0$ given that $B(x,r)\cap A$ is non-empty. Does that imply for all $r>0$ one can get $$B(x,r)\cap A\cap D$$ is non-empty? Basically want to show that if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ the  it is also a limit point of $A\cap D.$

Comment: I edited the question and suppose this make sense. Sorry to bother you.